# Resetting MobX observable after Array.splice

Tags: arrays, reactjs, mobx

I'm trying to use Array.splice to remove an element from an array at an index. This Array is observable within a MobX store. I know that I cannot use `splice` on a MobX array as that will just return it back to a standard Array, and no longer observable.

I need to use the index to remove the item, because there could be items with duplicate values, so using the filter workaround here will not work: [Array splice is not observed by mobx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57827779/array-splice-is-not-observed-by-mobx)

So what I am trying to do is modify the Array using `splice`, and then *re-observing* the animalList property, however this gives a `Cannot convert 'LivestockStore@1.animalList' into observable object: The target is already observable of different type.` error.

'''

```
export default class LivestockStore {

    animalList:Animal[] = new Array<Animal>();

    constructor() {
        makeAutoObservable(this);
    }

    removeAnimal = (index: number) => {
        const animalListModified = this.animalList;
        animalListModified.splice(index, 1);
        this.animalList = makeObservable(animalListModified);
    }
}
```

I cannot store the `index` in the animal object, because for each time one is removed, I would have to re-calculate all the `Index` values. My only other option for this would be to use a Map and store a Guid as a `key` for each element and delete from that, however this seems like a hack to fix something that should be relatively simple.

Cheers,
Justin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know that I cannot use splice on a MobX array as that will just return it back to a standard Array, and no longer observable.

You absolutely can use `splice` here (and should, mutations in MobX is the right way), it does not matter what array it returns because you don't need that part at all in your case. (it returns removed elements)

[Codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/httpsstackoverflowcomquestions68479552-x7ny4?file=/src/App.js)

So just use `splice` without any additional code:

```
  removeAnimal = (index) => {
    this.animalList.splice(index, 1);
  };
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. That is what my original code was doing, however the `observing` of the list of items is then lost. In my store, I have the following getter: `get getAnimals() { return this.animalList; }` and then to display the rows, I have: `{getAnimals.map((item, index) => ( <Table.Row key={index}>... display row JSX ... </Table.Row>
)` however the UI is not refreshed. If I toggle the visibility of the component it refreshed, however the `observability` of the array is lost, and the UI is not updated when the buttons `onClick={() => removeAnimal(index)}` is clicked?

Comment: The observability is not lost, you are wrong here. There is something else in your code that does not work, but it is not the array (as you can see in my example). Probably your table component (it comes from some library?) does not support observables. You would need to provide example of your rendering component then

Comment: Hmm, something else is definitely going on, and I'm quite stumped now. This is how my code is laid out, and this is working fine: https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-stallman-vtju7 - Obviously there is other things going on in my app, however the form for this is onyl wrapped in a Formik form, which could be causing some issues. I might have to do some further investigations. Thanks again.